# Mostrar informações de um dataframe em um mapa shapefile

Tags: r

Tenho uma tabela .dta que já importei para o R. Uma das colunas desse arquivo chama-se "mun" e tem o código dos municípios do Brasil, um número de 7 digitos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei o [Shapefile](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/Brasil/BR/) do site do **IBGE** 
que vem todos os arquivos: `.cpj`, `.dbf`, `.prj`, `.shp`, `.shx`

Usei o `maptools` e importei o mapa para o `R`. O mapa já possui as informações dos códigos dos municípios como: `CD_GEOCMU`

```
require(maptools)
mapa<-readShapeSpatial(file.choose())
```

Meu arquivo tem mais de 4 milhões de dados com seus respectivos códigos dos municípios. Eu preciso colocar estes dados no mapa com uma escala de cor para poder ver legal a distribuição destes dados no Brasil, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Agradeço muito se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a função [`geom_map`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_map.html), da biblioteca `ggplot2`, é justamente que você está procurando. Tem uns exemplos similares na documentação que linkei. Grosso modo, basicamente você basicamente usa o parametro `fill` para definir qual variável usar para preencher as regiões.

[Este artigo](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) explica passo-a-passo como tratar os dados de modo a se adequarem melhor à lógica da ggplot2.